# QueryRunner Insert method Return Type

Tags: java, sql, spring, apache-commons-dbutils

I am using Apache Commons DBUtils according to [QueryRunner#insert](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbutils/QueryRunner.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20org.apache.commons.dbutils.ResultSetHandler)) method in its documentation, insert return the generic type of ResultSetHandler. I have a BR_Author object for my project.

***BR_Author.java***

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class BR_Author {
    private int id;
    private String authorName;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAuthorName() {
        return authorName;
    }

    public void setAuthorName(String authorName) {
        this.authorName = authorName;
    }
}
```

I write a simple insert statement at my service class like

***AuthorService#createAuthor***

```
public BR_Author createAuthor(String authorName) throws ApiException {
        String sql = "Insert into BR_AUTHOR(authorName) VALUES(?)";
        ResultSetHandler<BR_Author> rs = new BeanHandler<BR_Author>(
                BR_Author.class);
        QueryRunner qr = new QueryRunner(dataSource);
        Object[] params = { authorName };
        try {
            BR_Author author = qr.insert(sql, rs, params);
            System.out.println("Br_Author:" + author);
            return author;

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new ApiException(ErrorCode.ERR20001, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I am trying to return the added value at the createAuthor method, but if i configure the id field as auto-increment object return as

```
Br_Author:Br_Author [id=0, authorName=null]
```

when I check the db I see that it adds the values successfully.

If I disable auto-increment and set the id from the code, the author object is null. So I want to learn that am I misunderstood the QueryRunner#insert method or if it has a bug. I already checked the below links.

- [QueryRunner_insert_add_javadoc.patch](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12541287/QueryRunner_insert_add_javadoc.patch)
- [Generated key handling for updates](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DBUTILS-54)

***BTW:*** Select queries working fine for the BR_Author class so it means there shouldn't be any mapping issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any official solution from [DBUtils API](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/) so i just return generated ID and then query it after insert the record with this id at Service layer. This way method return Object at service layer, but i do one extra query.

Answer (score 1):

the ResultSet of QueryRunner.insert return value only has one param that is the GENERATED_KEY of the record, you can get with rs.getInteger

```
Integer id = qr.insert(sql, rs -> rs.next() ? rs.getInteger("GENERATED_KEY") : null, params);
```

then query with this id